# Adaptive Rendering in ASP.net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms

If there an equivilent of adaptive rendering in ASP.net Web Forms i.e. using a different markup for a mobile browser?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
What you are looking for is [Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx)

> With the control adapter architecture, it is possible to completely
>   change the rendering of individual controls based on the type of
>   browser that is being used to make the request, without any
>   modifications to the controls themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IsMobileDevice property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can use this to render different content for mobile devices.